# How to convert sql query to entity framework core

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-6, entity-framework-core

I want to convert sql query to entity framework core.
SQL query is

```
select * from Departments where id in(select DepartmentId from SubDepartments where id in(select SubDeptId from Tests where id in(select TestId from PatientTests where PatientId=3)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Linqer](http://www.sqltolinq.com/).

Linqer is a SQL to LINQ conversion tool. It helps to learn LINQ and convert existing SQL statements.

Comment: Good tool if using Microsoft SQL. I am using postgres sql and hence I cannot give the connection in the tool as it expects only MS sql server. Even i want my query to be converted to a LINQ query. Any solutions for my problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming navigation properties are implemented, and without having any example code, this is a best estimate of how to implement it.

```
context.Departments.Where(x => x.SubDepartment.Test.PatientTest.PatientId == 3);
```